# Get the same object to ListView Android

Tags: java, android

I tried to develope my first app in Android and I have a mistake. I need to get objects from SQLite db and show them in ListView. Here is the code of my Adapter:

```
public class ReminderListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Reminder> {
private Context mContext;
private int mResource;

public ReminderListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Reminder> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    int id = getItem(position).getId();
    String name = getItem(position).getName();
    String hour = getItem(position).getHour();
    String date = getItem(position).getDate();

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

    TextView resId = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textId);
    TextView resName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
    TextView resHour = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textHour);
    TextView resDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);

    resId.setText(String.valueOf(id));
    resName.setText(name);
    resHour.setText(hour);
    resDate.setText(date);

    return convertView;
}
```

Here is code of activity where I need to post objects from db:

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DBHelper dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase database;
private ListView listView;
private TextView countRem;
private String count;
ArrayList<Reminder> ReminderList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListOfReminders);
    countRem =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);



    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_REMINDERS, null, null,null,null,null,null);
    getRemindersCount();
    count = Integer.toString(getRemindersCount());
    countRem.setText(count);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME);
        int hourIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_HOUR);
        int dateIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_DATE);
        String name = Integer.toString(nameIndex);
        String hour = Integer.toString(hourIndex);
        String date = Integer.toString(dateIndex);
        do{
            ReminderList.add(new Reminder(idIndex, name, hour, date));
            ReminderListAdapter adapter = new ReminderListAdapter(this, R.layout.reminder_view, ReminderList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    } else
        Log.d("mLog", "0 rows in db");

}

public int getRemindersCount(){
    long NrOfReminders = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database, TABLE_REMINDERS);
    int count = (int)NrOfReminders;
    return count;
}
```

On the result, I get the same output in my listview. Obj1: id:0,name:1,hour:2,date:3. This data are not matching with data in db. And also, this output is for every object. What is the mistake? I'm sorry if it is a stupid mistake, it's first app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.getColumnIndex(...)` only returns the column index for the row. To get the value in that column, you have a few options:

- If you know the data type in advance, you can directly call the corresponding method on the `cursor`. For example, if the column `DBHelper.KEY_NAME` contains a `String`, we can query the value in that column directly using `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME))`
- If you don't, you can try calling [`cursor.getType(int columnIndex)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getType(int)) to get the underlying type, then call the appropriate method on the cursor based on the returned value.

In short, the issue with your code is that you are getting the column *indices* (`getColumnIndex`) instead of the column *values* (`getFloat`, `getInt`, `getString` etc.):

```
    ...
    int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME);
    int hourIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_HOUR);
    int dateIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_DATE);
    String name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
    String hour = cursor.getString(hourIndex);
    String date = cursor.getString(dateIndex);
  ...
```